# basic_ofstream<int> vs. basic_ofstream<char>

Tags: c++, file, file-io, char, ofstream

I trying to understand `std::basic_ofstream`. I started with this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream test_stream("data.txt");
    int my_int = 12;
    double my_double = 26.8;
    test_stream << my_int << " " << my_double;
}
```

When you open `data.txt` in Notepad, you see

```
12 26.8
```

This told me that `<<` formatted the output and stored the output as `char`s ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)). Indeed, the size of `data.txt` was 7 bytes.

I wanted to output my data as raw bits to prevent conversion to strings. I found I could do that with `write`:

```
test_stream.write((char*) & my_int, 4);
test_stream.write((char*) & my_double, 8);
```

This functionally does what I want/expected. `data.txt` will appear as 12 bytes that are the little endian, binary representation of 12 and 26.8. However, I was hoping for some nicer notation. I tried the `put` member function, but that only outputs 1 byte of the `int`.

I then considered the possibility of changing `basic_ofstream`'s character type to `int`. My hope was that I could do something like this

```
int main() {
    std::basic_ofstream<int> test_stream("data.txt");
    int my_int = 123412431;
    test_stream.put(my_int);
}
```

or this

```
int main() {
    std::basic_ofstream<int> test_stream("data.txt");
    int my_int = 123412431;
    test_stream << my_int;
}
```

The first gives only 1 byte output `Ï`. The second gives an error. I assumed that the point of `std::basic_ofstream<int>` would be to overload `put` to transfer `int`s.

### Question

So what is the difference between `std::basic_ofstream<int>` and `std::basic_ofstream<char>`? Is there a way to make `std::basic_ofstream<int>` do what I want? (for clarity: what I want is the functionality of the `write` example with `put` or `<<`.)

Comment: switching the CharT on ostream is a huge level of pain for little gain - you'd have to define, at least, char traits and applicable locale facets (e.g. you'll need a `codecvt` for your type if only just so the stream calls `always_noconv` on it).. and even then I wouldn't trust it to always work. At that point it'd be easier to write a stream type from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is not a character type. You cannot use it as template argument to `std::basic_ostream`.

(Technically it may be supported as implementation-defined character type, but I don't think any implementation actually does that.)

Only `char` (corresponding to `std::ostream`) and `wchar_t` (corresponding to `std::wostream`) are generally supported.

---

Your approach of outputting the object representation with `std::ofstream`  is correct and how it should be done, except that you should use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` instead of `(char*)` and that you should use `sizeof(/*variable name*/)` instead of a magic number. Both of these help avoid mistakes.

You can wrap that in a function to have nicer notation which doesn't require repeating the variable name twice:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& print_object_representation(std::ostream& o, const T& t) {
    // Use `std::addressof(t)` instead of `&t` to
    // correctly handle classes with overloaded `operator&`
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
    return o;
}

//...

print_object_representation(test_stream, my_double);
```

Comment: Why not ```static_cast<const char*>```?

Comment: @MarkWallace Because that doesn't compile.

Comment: @MarkWallace `static_cast` does not allow accessing the object representation. The casts allowed with `static_cast` are value conversions which are generally relatively safe (i.e. you can't cast between completely unrelated types) and pointer conversions inside class hierarchies. You can't use `static_cast` to arbitrarily cast pointers. Accessing the object representation is a very special case and delegated to `reinterpret_cast` which also allows for other much less safe pointer conversions (and which you should therefore almost never use for anything else).